# A broken stylus stuck inside the phone

Tags: technology

I have a Samsung Tablet A with S Pen. That tablet has a dedicated slot for an S Pen. The problem is, why
S Pen is broken into half, so when I inserted the S Pen into that slot, the S Pen is stuck and won't come out. I tried to shake it, but it won't come out. I tried to use a pair of the inside of a ballpoint and a pair of needle, but it still won't go out either.

How do I take the S Pen out without destroying the pen/phone in the process?

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. (Hack) Apply at the and of a thin "stick" some quick curing glue. While the glue is still fresh, insert it in the phone, make sure the glue sticks only to the broken stylus fragment (and not to the phone). Carefully extract both the stick and the stylus fragment.
2. (Proper solution) Take the phone to a smartphone repair shop. They will (partially) disassemble the phone, extract the stylus fragment, and reassemble it again. They might even have some better / easier solution that this.

Note: the hack is relatively dangerous, because the glue can adhere to the phone also, and as a result you amplify the problem - possibly to the point that even a good repair shop cannot do a good job any more.

Comment: Guess that I'll go to the repair shop. How much does it cost?

Comment: About the cost, your guess is as good as mine. I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I guess that I'll ask the nearest servicer. But how do you pry open the back cover first?

Comment: I have no idea. The people at the service should know. If they don't know, then don't trust them.